# Custom zoom buttons for osmdroid

Tags: java, android, controls, zooming, osmdroid

I'm trying to build custom zoom controls for osmdroid. 
I create button and use zoom-in method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844184/android-mapview-custom-zoom-buttons)
But nothing happens when i click on button.
Here is my code:

```
private MapView map;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(false);
}

    public void myClickHandler(View target) {
        switch (target.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                map.getController().zoomIn();
                break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wire the click handle to the button

FindViewById (...).setClickListener (...)