# Smooth zoom in Android MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a MapView with one overlay. Overlay renders tile based map over the MapView. I use MapView.getZoomLevel() to retrieve current zoom level for Google map and for my tiles. Everything works just perfect, but only if user don't zoom the map using multitouch gestures. As I understand, the MapView control don't render actual tiles during zooming process, but just show stretched screen content. So, the question is - How to get this scale ratio which I can use to render my tiles exactly in same way as Google do?

Thank You!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6308613/646806)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the method `MapView.getZoomLevel()` isn't aligned with zoom changes animation and multitouche, the methods `MapView.getProjection().fromPixels()` and `MapView.getProjection().fromPixels()` are.

So you have several option to adress the issue. From the methos above, you can find the direct `(x,y)` coordinates (and size) where to render the tiles or you can find the zoom ration using something like:

```
int lonSpan = projection.fromPixels(0,mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6() - 
    projection.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth(),mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6();
```

which gives you the longitude span at map vertical center. Then, you divide the value after zoom starts from the value before zoom starts.

Regards.

Comment: Thanx. Your proposal looks exactly what I've done yesterday, but I thought that there should be direct way to get information about MapView Zoom magic... BTW, how to know when zoom starts?

Comment: BTW, Is there any _normal_ way to know when zoom starts, because right know I do it by very unusual way (by checking number of touches)?

Comment: Probably, you don't need to know when zoom started. At least I don't. What I do, is to compare the last used `lonSpan` with current value. If they are different, then I need to recalculate points and redraw the overlay because zoom changed since last redraw. If the are the same I can used the last calculated points (they didn't change) to redraw the overlay.

Comment: If this isn't enough, let me know, and I'll give you a hint on how to check when zoom realy started, but that will not be that simple due to zoom animation timmings. It requires to post a runnable with some time delay on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` que get the zoom ending value for `lonSpan` and compare it with the value get on `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`.